# jquery jtable doesn't execute listAction function

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have the following code (from the site examples)

```
$('#reportsTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Table of people',
    actions: {
        listAction: function (postData, jtParams) {
            ret = {
                "Result": "OK",
                "Records": [{
                    "PersonId": 1,
                    "Name": "Benjamin Button",
                    "Age": 17,
                    "RecordDate": "\/Date(1320259705710)\/"
                }]
            }
            return ret;
        },
    },
    fields: {
        PersonId: {
            key: true,
            list: false
        },
        Name: {
            title: 'Author Name',
            width: '40%'
        },
        Age: {
            title: 'Age',
            width: '20%'
        },
        RecordDate: {
            title: 'Record date',
            width: '30%',
            type: 'date',
            create: false,
            edit: false
        }
    }
});
$('#reportsTableContainer').jtable('load');


}; // end initJTable
```

when I run it I get in the console -

```
http://localhost/valuepro/valuepro/main/function%20(postData,%20jtParams)%20%7Bret%20=%20%7B%20%22Result%22:%22OK%22,%20%22Records%22:[%20%20%7B%22PersonId%22:1,%22Name%22:%22Benjamin%20Button%22,%22Age%22:17,%22RecordDate%22:%22//Date(1320259705710)//%22%7D,%20%20%7B%22PersonId%22:2,%22Name%22:%22Douglas%20Adams%22,%22Age%22:42,%22RecordDate%22:%22//Date(1320259705710)//%22%7D,%20%20%7B%22PersonId%22:3,%22Name%22:%22Isaac%20Asimov%22,%22Age%22:26,%22RecordDate%22:%22//Date(1320259705710)//%22%7D,%20%20%7B%22PersonId%22:4,%22Name%22:%22Thomas%20More%22,%22Age%22:65,%22RecordDate%22:%22//Date(1320259705710)//%22%7D%20]%7Dreturn%20ret;%7D
```

i.e. instead of executing the function it turns it into a string and tries to fetch it from the SRV.

Why is that? what is wrong with this code?

How should I execute a function from the listAction instead of fetching the data from the SRV?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to version 2.4.0 solve this problem